# Firefox won't load .eot files via Amazon cloudfront

Tags: firefox, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm hosting font files in amazon S3 and cloudfront.

When displaying my webpages with Firefox, I can see the font files are being loaded, but the download never ends.

If I deactivate the CDN, firefox gets the files normally from my host server.

It also works perfectly fine on chrome, safari and IE with and without the CDN.

I just cannot figure this problem out. Some help would be well appreciated!!

[Screenshot of firefox network pannel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pnDs.png)

[My Website here](http://www.escapar.com.co)

Comment: I found out that firefox doesn't support font-face when the font file is hosted on another domain.

Workaround here : http://geoff.evason.name/2010/05/03/cross-domain-workaround-for-font-face-and-firefox/

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your CDN is not sending the right response headers to allow cross-domain linking?  The CSS fonts spec requires the Firefox behavior.  See http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-fonts/#default-same-origin-restriction